# Xcode/WatchKit - how do I run the regular app on iPad/other devices?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, xcode, apple-watch

Could anyone please tell me, now that I have added a WatchKit target to my application, if it is possible to just run the main target on devices which don't support the watch (i.e. the original part of the app which worked on iPads and iPhoneOS < 8?).

Xcode keeps telling me I can no longer run the main app target (not the watchkit target) on my iPad because:

`Ineligible Devices : My iPad (Apple Watch not supported)`

Does this mean I will have to keep two versions of my project- one for WatchKit apps and one for non-WatchKit apps?!

All I want to do is run and debug the main app, part of a larger project which includes a Watch interface, on a device which cannot pair with an Apple Watch. Apologies if this has been asked already, some Monday google-foo couldn't find an answer; also please feel free to edit the question if it seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a completely non-issue.

Restart the device.

Answered here to keep the keywords for search, in case (like I did) others assume that it's a WatchKit issue, not a device/xCode connection issue.

Comment: which device? The phone, the watch, the PC?

Answer (score 0):

I really always wants to run the apps without Xcode but failed many times. This time i found one fantastic article about installing of side loading apps without Xcode. [Sideload iOS Apps Without Xcode](http://windowspcguide.com/sideload-ios-apps-windows-mac-without-xcode-jailbreak-cydia-impactor/) on Windows/Mac [iPhone/iPad] that too without jailbreak.

Comment: This has exactly zero to do with the question.